# Termo para aquele que discorda

Tags: significado, palavra-para-ideia

Que substantivo se usa para aquele que discorda?

Pensei na palavra *discordante*, mas parece ser apenas um adjectivo...

Comment: algumas palavras: do contra, divergente, contestador, intolerante

Comment: @AndréLyra não concordo com a palavra 'intolerante'. o significado é bastante diferente

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Discordante*** é, além de adjetivo, também substantivo. É verdade que  alguns dicionários, como o [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=discordante) ou o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/discordante), classificam a palavra *discordante* apenas como adjetivo, mas outros classificam-na também como substantivo. Veja-se por exemplo [*discordante* (4) no Aulete:](http://www.aulete.com.br/discordante)

> s2g [substantivo de dois géneros]
> **4.** Pessoa discordante.: *Os discordantes permaneçam sentados*.

Eis alguns exemplos reais (ênfase minha):

> Já transpus os limites da discrição, e numa sociedade primitiva e guerreira como esta, democracia pela força das cousas mas sem nenhuma educação liberal, e em que a regra é eliminar ***os discordantes***, com o que disse já estou muito mal parado. [[João do Rio, *O Momento Literário*, 1907.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=oYpcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT22&lpg=PT22&dq=%22eliminar%20os%20discordantes%22&source=bl&ots=T5We9Kl27L&sig=GJmb3wrd1i8sfiLFxYtDCsi2haU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA4ujD2uTMAhVLthoKHfH6DVEQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22eliminar%20os%20discordantes%22&f=false)
>
> **2.** Tratando-se de perícia colegial, se não houver unanimidade, ***o discordante*** apresentará as suas razões. [[Pedro Pinheiro Torres, *Guia para o Novo Código de Processo Civil*, 2013.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=hdErAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT479&dq=%22o%20discordante%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG7qSD3eTMAhUBmBoKHdS1DgwQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=%22o%20discordante%22&f=false)

Comment: Poderia ser usado a palavra opositor também?

Comment: @sumitani Em muitos contextos provavelmente poderia. Mas *opositor* é aquele que se opõe. Como *discordar* e *opor-se* não são perfeitamente equivalentes, em muitos contextos *opositor* não resultaria muito bem. Por exemplo, no segundo exemplo da minha resposta, não creio que *opositor* servisse bem.

Comment: Obrigado Jacinto ;)

Comment: No segundo exemplo, não me parece inteiramente claro se há de facto uma reacategorização de _discordante_ em substantivo, ou se há apenas elipse de _perito_.

Comment: O sufixo -nte segue sendo produtivo, mas agora só para fazer adjetivos com verbos principalmente intransitivos (antes, era forma verbal que podia encabeçar cláusulas inteiras). Mas como regra geral no português, todo adjetivo pode sustantivar-se, e isso é muito frequente como os *-nte* (uma pessoa que estuda > uma pessoa estudante > um/a estudante). Por essas razões, com frequência palavras de este tipo omitem-se no dicionário porque o significado é transparente.